# Formula to list values not duplicating from two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns with values.

```
Column1   Column2
a           b
b           e
c           f
d
e
f
```

Any way to make a forumla on a separate column that checks for duplicates between the columns 1 and 2, and lists all the values that did not have duplicates?

Like this:

```
Column3
a
c
d
```

Comment: http://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-3-ways-to-extract-unique-values.html

Comment: Yes I know how to do it with advanced filtering, but I would like to know if it's possible to do with a formula.

Comment: the link has 2 more ways of doing it with array formula and VBA macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))-ROW($A$1)+1)/(COUNTIFS($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)),$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))=0),ROW(1:1))),IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)))-ROW($B$1)+1)/(COUNTIFS($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)))=0),ROW(1:1)-SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNTIFS($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)),$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))=0)))),""))
```

Put this in C1 and copy down.

All the `$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))` are setting the extents of the dataset.  With array formulas we want to limit the number of iterations to only the dataset.

The `INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))` returns the last cell in column A with text in it.

If your column is numbers change the `"ZZZ"` to `1E+99`.

[image: ![enter image description here]